# RestSharp and special characters like æ ø å, in response.Content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp in my Windows Phone 8 project. And it worked great, up until i had a response.Content containing special chars like "æ" "ø" "å". They all gets transformed to "�", i know this means theres some kind of encoding problem, but is it RestSharp thats not able to handle these chars or is it my own doing?.

Heres an example of how a username pulled from a database looks like after calling it with RestSharp: name=\"Bj�rnar\" the name of this user in my databse is "bjørnar"

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please add an answer to your question instead of editing it. Please note that "don't use X" isn't an answer, at least not by itself. If you expand it to something like "X doesn't support Y because Z," and provide evidence that it can't be done, that would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the extension method](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Extensions/MiscExtensions.cs) `public static string AsString(this byte[] buffer)` in `MiscExtensions` in RestSharp. This method takes different types of encoding into account, including Unicode which appears to be what you are looking for.